# Alternative front-end to Excel 2007 for SSAS Cube

Tags: excel, ssas, cube

A few months ago I built a set of SSAS cubes to be accessed via Excel 2007 for our team. Excel was then preferred as a front-end because business users were already familiar with excel and with the pivot table interface.

But now complaints have risen about the interface being too 'basic' and not user-friendly enough - specifically people would like to see hover-over tool-tips (or something similar) when they hover over fields in the pivot table, that will be able to give them a bit more information.

A custom .NET front-end solution would probably be ideal, but a) I don't have that level of .NET skills, and b) I don't have too much time left on this project to build something from scratch and roll it out.

Would like to hear from people here about any off-the-shelf suggestions for alternatives, that an SSAS cube can be plugged into. Thanks.

Comment: Well one negative vote but no ideas. Not sure if I posted in the wrong forum, or if this sort of question is unlikely to get responses for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

PowerPivot is the right choice for you as it has all the dimension selection options and on the fly calculated members and calculated measures features inbuilt but the solution only works with office 2010 onwards

Comment: Thanks, we did give Powerpivot a go. It seemed that you first download data from the cube to your local machine as a flat file, which is then fed in to PowerPivot? I am looking for a client tool that can connect to data on the server and execute queries against it.

Comment: you can design a custom query interface using syncfusion controls or Kropka Olap controls, i assume syncfusion will be more right choice it has lot of designer controls and have extensive flexibility